# Inconsistency in "View History" for GitHub plugin in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have recently installed GitHub for Visual Studio 2015 and started to use it.

When I want to revert to a previous commit, I'm facing the following issue:

In Solution Explorer: Left-clicking on the project -> `Source Control` -> `View History` shows me just the initial commit.

However, going to Team Explorer: Left-clicking on active repository -> `View History` shows all commits.

Why do I experience this inconsistency?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the Solution Explorer, Source Control operations consider just the specific file you clicked on (in your case, the .vcxproj file). As far as I know this is how it works with every source control provider.

However, Team Explorer considers the entire repository, hence you see all the commits when viewing history.